# Show Intro Image in Joomla Category Listing menu

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0, joomla-template

I'm working on Joomla 3.4.5 and I added these two lines in my override file for **Category List** menu

```
$images  = json_decode($this->item->images);
<?php echo $article->images; ?>
```

and the result is this:

```
{"image_intro":"images\/articles\/liangmai2.jpg","float_intro":"","image_intro_alt":"","image_intro_caption":"","image_fulltext":"","float_fulltext":"","image_fulltext_alt":"","image_fulltext_caption":""}
```

The path `images\/articles\/liang2.jpg` is correct without the backslash. Now, How do I make this display it as `<img src="images/articles/liang2.jpg">` and also remove the backslash?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do changes in the file located at : Modules/mod_article_category/tmpl/default.php There in else condition i.e Not Grouped one add these lines in foreach loop in between your li tags :

```
 $article_images = $item->images; // Get image parameters of the article

 $pictures = json_decode($article_images); // Split the parameters apart

 echo "img src='" . $pictures->{'image_intro'} . "' alt='" . $pictures->{'image_intro_alt'} . "'>"; // get the intro image
```

Comment: Or even if the file is different, I hope the could will help you doing that

Comment: I got this working after posting the question but thank you :)